# Can I make [ $(($1 % $check)) -ne 0 ]; be more performant and not be killed?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, performance

If have the following code which works for up to 13 (line 2) in a few seconds but when I try and do upper teens and 20 it gets killed after a couple of minutes.

```
divisible_by () {
  for ((check=2; check<13; check++)) {
    if [ $(($1 % $check)) -ne 0 ]; then
      return
    fi  
  }
  echo "$1 is divisible by all the numbers"
  exit 0
}
d=0
while true; do
  d=$((d+1))
  divisible_by $d
done
```

I tried using

```
if $(($1 % $check)) -ne 0; then
```

but I get `1: command not found`

I tried

```
if $(($1 % $check)) -ne 0; then
```

but I got `1:command not found` and `-ne command not found`

I tried

```
 if [ $($1 % $check) -ne 0 ]; then
```

but I got `1:command not found` and `-ne: unary operator expected`

I tried

```
 if [ $1 % $check -ne 0 ]; then
```

but I got `[: too many arguments`

Comment: I suspect that it is killed because of an integer overflow in `d=$((d+1))`: `d` gets too large. If the shell integer precision is not sufficient for you, then do not write a shell script.

Comment: I'm curious why you are doing this in bash. Is it just a learning exercise? Although some simple arithmetic is (obviously) possible in bash, it's really not suited for arithmetic work - the syntax is tedious and it's not very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the goal here is to find the lowest number divisible by integers 2 through n, trying to check every integer is massively inefficient. The easiest algorithm I can think of is to use an array of factors that will eventually be multiplied together to get the answer. It starts empty. Then, take each number in sequence, and divide out the factors that are already in our set of unique factors. Whatever is left is added to the set of unique factors, and we know that that set will be divisible by the current number. Since the product of that set contains the minimum set of prime factors that satisfies all necessary divisions, it is guaranteed to be the smallest number divisible by all numbers 2 through n.

```
upto=20
uniqueFactors=()
for ((i=2; i <= upto; i++)) 
do
  newFactors=$i
  for factor in "${uniqueFactors[@]}" #loop over array of factors
  do
    if [ $(($newFactors%$factor)) -eq 0 ]; then
      newFactors=$(($newFactors/$factor));
    fi;
  done
  uniqueFactors+=($newFactors);
done

product=1
for factor in "${uniqueFactors[@]}"
do
  product=$(bc <<< "$product*$factor") #use bc for numbers outside integer range
done

echo $product
```

This calculates the first number divisible by 2-20 (232792560) in 4 milliseconds on my machine. It calculates up to 100 (69720375229712477164533808935312303556800) in 0.425 seconds and 1000 (a number with several hundred decimal places) in 4.813 seconds. If you were to try to iterate over that many numbers, you'd have to be worried about your process getting killed by the heat death of the universe. Optimizing individual lines gives you improvements in percentages or orders of magnitude. Changing your algorithm can give you improvements on a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the fact that `((` returns zero when the result is non-zero:

```
if (( $1 % check )); then
  ...
fi
```

Comment: +1 I did that and it saved about 25%. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would iterate in decreasing order.  The loop can terminate sooner.

```
for ((check=12; check>1; --check)) {
```

instead of

```
for ((check=2; check<13; check++)) {
```

Just think about it.  If the number is not divisible by 12, it's not divisible by 4, 3 and 2 either.  Not vice versa.

Comment: btw I assume you meant `check--` not `--check`

Comment: @MichaelDurrant No, I meant `--check`, but I don't think it matters.  Pre-decrement is faster in theory since you don't have to remember the previous value.  But that's most likely micro-optimization that won't have any real impact.